# It is possible to write SQL-request in android on cordova?

Tags: cordova

I start write a small app on cordova for android. I use openlayers and I need keep data in file system android in format `.db`. So it possible to write SQL-requests in cordova's app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use SQLlite via a plugin like https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage